# UITabBarController - how to make "no tabs" selected at start up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Is there any way in iPhone to unselect all tabs of a UITabBarController ? ie, my application has a "homepage" which does not belong to any tabs on the below displayed tabbar. Now when user touches any tab on the tabbar, I would like to load the corresponding tab. Is this possible ? I have already tried:

self.tabBarController.tabBarItem.enabled = NO;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = -1;

but this does not help. Any other solutions ? Please ?

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647756/unhighlight-uitabbaritem-in-uitabbarcontroller

Answer (score 7):

I've managed to accomplish this using [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/KeyValueObserving_QuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html) tricks.

The idea is simple: we track down when UITabBarController tries to set its selectedViewController property and immediately set it back to nil.

Example code:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the view controller which will be displayed after application startup
    mHomeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [tabBarController.view addSubview:mHomeViewController.view];
    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    [tabBarController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedViewController" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

    // further initialization ...
}

// This method detects if user taps on one of the tabs and removes our "Home" view controller from the screen.
- (BOOL) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (!mAllowSelectTab)
    {
        [mHomeViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        mAllowSelectTab = YES;
    }

    return YES;
}

// Here we detect if UITabBarController wants to select one of the tabs and set back to unselected.
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (!mAllowSelectTab)
    {
        if (object == tabBarController && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"selectedViewController"])
        {
            NSNumber *changeKind = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeKindKey];

            if ([changeKind intValue] == NSKeyValueChangeSetting)
            {
                NSObject *newValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

                if ([newValue class] != [NSNull class])
                {
                    tabBarController.selectedViewController = nil;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, one small note: the first view controller from tabbar still will be loaded (although for a very short time), so its viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear will be called after startup. You may want to add some logic to prevent some initializations you probably may do in these functions until "real" display of that controller as a result of user tap (using for example global variables or NSNotificationCenter).

Comment: First of all,really sorry for responding this late. U saved my day. I have been searching everywhere for a proper solution! It works and it works perfect .But I have just one doubt, I tried setting the selectedViewController to nil directly inside the code (without the observer method) ,it never worked .Any guess on why it is so ? And can you please explain me the observer method ? I understood the overall picture, but didn't understand it line by line ...

Answer (score 0):

Showing a tab bar with no tab selected would break user experience. A tab bar should always have one element selected and show the appropriate page - everything else is confusing.

So if you need to show something else, you should make it a popover (i.e. a sliding sheet from the bottom) that can be dismissed.

Comment: I agree. But my client wants this ! The expectation is to show a "home page" (separate view controller)and a tabbar, with no tabs selected. When user clicks on any tab, the corresponding view controller has to be loaded. ie, the homepage has to be a view controller which does not belong to any of the tabs ? any ideas ? please help ?

Comment: I dont know if this will be accepted to the app store, even if you get it working. Why not try adding a view above the TabControllerView on start up?

Comment: Look at the search part of the Youtube app on iPad.  (If you still have iOS5 that is)

Comment: The app store itself on iOS6 on iPhone will present a view showing the tab bar with all items selected.

Comment: @kylef Well, this answer is two years old. :) I think the AppStore sometimes selects none, not all - but I couldn't reproduce it now at all. Maybe it's fixed now, I remember being "surprised and disoriented" when I faced that situation, as I was a bit lost in navigation.

Comment: It's east to duplicate. Just tap on an App Store link in Mobile Safari. It will open the app in the App Store with no tabs selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UITabBar` to your view controller and manage the buttons manually from there, via `UITabBarDelegate`. Your view controller would be the "base" view, like a homepage.

This is relatively easy to do, unless you want the special "More..." view controller that `UITabBarController` provides, which you'd have to implement yourself.